# How To Remove ^M From Sequence Element

Tags: clojure

I've had a brain freeze and need help figuring out the best way to remove a \return \newline characters from one or more sequence elements. I know \return is 13 and \newline is 10. I need help figuring out how to use that in a map or filter.

I am receiving data back from a program that is turned into a vector and looks like this

```
AT|254 Torrence Ave||Scuffington|ZA|12345|7248|541|C029^M\n
|11|900036|e|
```

but should look like this:

```
AT|254 Torrence Ave||Scuffington|ZA|12345|7248|541|C029|11|900036|e|
```

What is the best way to remove the carriage return?

I've tried filter, but do not know how to represent a `<CR>`, so that the filter is giving me all elements that are not a `<CR>`.

Comment: ^M is ASCII 13.  Does that help at all?

Comment: Sorry, no it does not help, because I need to know how to filter out that number from the string.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that this is a CR and not a literal `^` followed by a `M`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clojure code for a ^M (character nr 13) literal is `\return`, and `"\r"` if part of a string literal.

So you can use something like:

```
(apply str (filter (fn [c] (not= c \return)) "string with \r characters"))
```

Comment: Your answer works with a test string "This is a test.\return", but does not work with what I've listed. If you've got any other thoughts, I'd love them. I'm keeping your answer accepted, because it works, but not for my example.

Comment: You probably have return AND newline characters in your string. So you should then check for `\newline` and `\return`

Comment: I was just about to post that. There are \return \newline chars.